# ruby: how can I select multiple elements of an array_of_array and count occurring cases?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I figured already out how to work with ar_of_ar, but can't select multiple elements of only the second column.

```
temp_ary=CSV.read(file, {col_sep->";"})
```

the mounted file has the structure:

```
[Date, value]  
june6;1200.02  
jul6;500.04    
dec06; 3400.07
```

after having imported, I want to count the values which are greater than 1000. However, the normal adressing I'm used to does not work, thus selecting values 1..3 of column2:

```
temp_ary[2..3][1]
```

only returns the first value?

I'm not sure whatever values I can expect, but I want to count occurring `nil`, `null`, `0`, space values and so on, which are no real numbers. How can I efficiently do that?

Comment: Please note that there is no such thing as `null` in Ruby, there is only `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
require "csv"

def csv
  @csv ||= CSV.read("./test.csv", :col_sep => ';')
end

puts csv.count {|x| x.last.to_i > 1000}
```

You can pass a "block" to the count method to specify a predicate to count on.
See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-count

Also you might not be interested by the method "csv" and so on. The hard work is done by the count method.

EDIT: If you just wanted to select certain values of you CSV file. I suggest taking a look at the method "values_at": http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at

```
csv.values_at(0..1).count {|x| x.last.to_i > 1000}
```

Comment: How could i adress elements here? I do not want to count "all", but only for certain elements (i editted the question to be clearer? could you briefly explain me the def @ and || part? thank you a lot!

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer Explaining how basic Ruby constructs like method definitions and instance variables work is far beyond the scope of your question, and an indicator that you should read a Ruby tutorial or book.

Comment: thank you for the help. yes you are right i should go further into the docs, but i only try to verify a small programm, and there are (which is very nice) a big variety of different ways of conducting it in ruby.. in any case thanks your fast support